# Routing leads back to originating page

Tags: html, angular, twitter-bootstrap-3, html-select, bootstrap-select

I'm developing a web application using Angular 6. I'm using the bootstrap library **bootstrap-select** (https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/) 
to create combo boxes (which allow search functionality). I have this problem:

My application consists of several pages (created thanks to the *Angular routing mechanism*); this code seems to work correctly:

```
<select class="form-control selectpicker" data-width="250px" data-live-search="true" 
        title="Select the right value" data-size="10">
    <option value="a">Value 1</option>
    <option value="b">Value 2</option>
    <option value="c">Value 3</option>
</select>
```

and the `<select>` is displayed graphically (the path is: `http://localhost:4200/page1`):

[image]

unfortunately, if I go somewhere else (in some another logic path of my application, for example: `http://localhost:4200/page2`) 
and then return to the page where I was before (`http://localhost:4200/page1`), the `<select>` disappears!!
[image]

I'm sure the problem comes from the library, that is `class="form-control selectpicker"`, (without this command the behavior is correct) but I don't understand why this thing happens and how I can do to solve the problem! Thanks.

Comment: Looks like the plugin will initialize the dropdown once on window load. When you destroy page1 and come back, the dropdown needs to be initialized again. Can you try adding `$('.selectpicker').selectpicker();` to `ngOnInit()` of your page1 component?

Comment: I did, but the situation doesn't change...

Comment: In your second screenshot, is the `<select class="form-control selectpicker"` present in the DOM if you inspect it? In `ngOnInit()` of page1, can you log the result of $('.selectpicker') to make sure the element exists?

Comment: If i inspect the DOM, the <select class="form-control selectpicker ng-tns-c2-14 ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid ng-star-inserted" data-live-search="true"> appears (even if nothing is displayed). If I log the result of $('.selectpicker') an existing object is always printed, but the lenght is 0 (if I print $('.selectpicker') for the first time, when it appears, the lenght property is 1)...

Comment: If you log `$('.selectpicker')` in `ngAfterViewInit()`, does it still have length 0?

Comment: In ngAfterViewInit() it works! Thanks a lot!!

Comment: No problem! :-)

Answer (score 0):

For me this worked

```
 ngAfterViewInit(){
  setTimeout(() => {
    $('.selectpicker').selectpicker();      
  },100);
 }
```